# rails - capistrano deployment of a subdirectory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I have a directory structure in git/github which looks like:

```
  demoapp
   - mockups
   - some_files
   - app (rails app)
```

the github url for the app looks like git@github/user/demoapp.git

Currently when I use capistrano to deploy, it looks for rake file in the directory demoapp and fails to find it.

How do I specify in capistrano deploy.rb the directory of my app (which is one level down).

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deploying a Git subdirectory in Capistrano](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29168/deploying-a-git-subdirectory-in-capistrano)

Comment: See :repo_tree instructions in the [update of this q](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29168/deploying-a-git-subdirectory-in-capistrano).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking through [Deploying a Git subdirectory in Capistrano](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29168/deploying-a-git-subdirectory-in-capistrano)

I ended up creating a separate repositories for my rails app and for other stuff.
The rails repository has all the artifacts like rake required by the capistrano script.

Answer (score 1):

if you can't split the repo, the only way is add extra cap callback

**after "deploy:update_code", "deploy:copy_to_level_up"**

```
namespace :deploy do
  desc "Copy code application to level up"
  task :copy_to_level_up do
    run "mv -R #{release_path}/ ....." #rewrite it with your conditions
  end
end
```