# Deploying with Capistrano when Rails Root is not Repo Root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, deployment, directory, capistrano

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Deploying a Git subdirectory in Capistrano](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29168/deploying-a-git-subdirectory-in-capistrano)

I've been developing an app for a while now and I'm deploying the back end to EC2 with Capistrano. However, the Github repository includes both the back end and the iOS front end. Say our Github clone URL is git@github.com:AwesomeCompany/AwesomeProject.git, and in the repository root is two directories, "FrontEnd" and "BackEnd". AwesomeProject/BackEnd would be my rails root, but I can't find a way to specify that to Capistrano.

Thanks for any help! (Sorry if this is a server fault question. I'm a developer stuck sysadmining and I think this is useful to other devs in the same boat.)