# Chef: deploy rails from git subfolder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, chef-infra, subdirectory

I'm using Chef to deploy a rails server. I'm storing my code in a git repository, but it's not the only item in the repository, it's in a subfolder

```
repo/
 project-files/
 more-project-files/
 rails-app/
```

Chef's deploy seems great, but it doesn't allow me to deploy from the subfolder (at least natively)
Is there a clever way of doing this, or am I stuck using `execute' to run the rake tasks myself?

Comment: As far as I can tell, capistrano can get and deploy a git repository, but not get a _subfolder_ from a git repository and deploy that. The rails app must be in the root folder, not a subfolder.

Comment: Check this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29168/deploying-a-git-subdirectory-in-capistrano/2047574#2047574

This works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decided to check out the entire project to a folder, and use symlinks to link in the folders we needed.

If we need to, we could use the Git built-in 'partial checkout' stuff, but we'd have to issue the command through *execute* instead of *deploy*. We'll investigate further if the project requires, but this works for now. Too bad that Chef's *deploy* doesn't have that functionality.